# PHP - Highlight Opening Hours

Tags: php

I can highlight the day by getting current date(). How can I highlight between two times (opening hours).

```
 <?php $day = date('l'); ?>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Monday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Tuesday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Tuesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Wednesday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Wednesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Thursday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Thursday: 9am - 6pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Friday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Friday: 9am - 6pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Saturday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Saturday: 9am - 4pm</div>
 <div<?php if ($day == "Sunday") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Sunday: 9am - 4pm</div>
```

I thought a way like below but this is not correct that I highlight also between the hours.

```
  <?php $day = date('l'); ?>
  <?php $time = date('h:i'); ?>
  <div<?php if ($day == "Monday" && ($time <= "9:00" || $time >= "6:00") { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
```

Would be happy for some help.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I am running PHP 5.5+

Comment: Sorry running PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `DateTime()`. It makes the code a little clearer. (I use `DateTimeImmutable()` which is only available in PHP 5.5+. If you are using an older version of PHP let me know and I can make this work for that version).

```
<?php 
    $now   = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $day   = $now->format('l');
    $open  = $now->setTime(9, 0);
    $close = $now->setTime(18, 0);
?>
<div<?php if ($day == "Monday"    && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Tuesday"   && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Tuesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Wednesday" && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Wednesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Thursday"  && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Thursday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Friday"    && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Friday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<?php 
    $close = $now->setTime(16, 0);
?>
<div<?php if ($day == "Saturday" && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Saturday: 9am - 4pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Sunday"   && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Sunday: 9am - 4pm</div>
```

Here is a PHP 5.3 version

```
<?php 
    $now   = new DateTime();
    $day   = $now->format('l');
    $open  = new DateTime();
    $open->setTime(9, 0);
    $close = new DateTime();
    $close->setTime(18, 0);
?>
<div<?php if ($day == "Monday"    && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Tuesday"   && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Tuesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Wednesday" && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Wednesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Thursday"  && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Thursday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Friday"    && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Friday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<?php 
    $close->setTime(16, 0);
?>
<div<?php if ($day == "Saturday" && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Saturday: 9am - 4pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day == "Sunday"   && $now > $open && $now < $close) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Sunday: 9am - 4pm</div>
```

Comment: Probably the best solution, assuming OP is running PHP 5.5+ though.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Yeah. It's less code when you can take advantage of an immutable DateTime object.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found in ... :(

Comment: Are you *sure* you are running PHP 5.5? What does `phpinfo();` say?

Comment: Sorry PHP Version 5.3 :)

Comment: Could you give me an Example with 24 Hour Format and with Minutes please?

Comment: I've updated the answer to work with PHP 5.3. Also this answer is already working in 24 hours. See where I call `setTime()`? The first one represents 9:00 and the second one represents 18:00 (6pm).

Comment: One correection `$now   = new DateTime(); $day = $now->format('l');`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that 24-hour clock is much easier to work with:

```
<?php
    $time = date('G');
    $date = date('N');
?>
<div<?php if ($day === "1" && $time >= 9 && $time <= 18) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day === "2" && $time >= 9 && $time <= 18) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Tuesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
<div<?php if ($day === "3" && $time >= 9 && $time <= 18) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Wednesday: 9am - 6pm</div>
etc...
```

It might be easier if you organize your opening hours data into an array and loop through that to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't compare strings like this with bigger than etc.

Try the same with only the hour

```
<?php $day = date('l'); ?>
  <?php $time = (int) date('H'); ?>
  <div<?php if ($day == "Monday" && ($time >= 9 || $time < 18)) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>Monday: 9am - 6pm</div>
```

Comment: This will highlight it when it is *closed*

Comment: Thx, for the tipp, edited it. I really like your solution, very clean

Comment: fixed it, I accidentally delete the second ) after 18.
In your code the ) is also missing at the end of the if

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$opentime = "9:00 am";
$closetime = "6:00 pm";
$day = date('l');
$time = date('h:i');
$open = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $opentime);
$close = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $closetime);

if ($day == "Monday"    && $time > $open && $time < $close) {
    echo 'Monday: 9am - 6pm';
}

etc........
```